# Proving the minimum cardinality of longest chain or longest antichain in $n$ element partial ordering

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory

> Let $(X, \le)$ be a partial ordering. Let $|X| = n$. $A$ is the longest antichain on $X$. $C$ is the longest chain on $X$. Prove that $|A| \ge \left[\sqrt{n-1}\right]+1 $ or $|C| \ge \left[\sqrt{n-1}\right] + 1$

I don't know how to tackle this problem. If anything was known about the ordering relation, Dilworth's theorem could be used. Any hints how to start?

Comment: Avoid no-clue question: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: I think the Erdős–Szekeres theorem is what you're looking for (note that it is sometimes phrased in terms of sequences).